# A 30 digit number, which starts with 4 and followed by 7, how many digits will be there when the 30 digit number will be cubed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question was asked in GATE 2017, and the options were 90,91,92,93.
I'm asking if there exists any mathematical formula to find this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the number you state in the question is larger than $47 \times 10^{28}$ and smaller than $48 \times 10^{28}$. Now note the fact that $$10^6>48^3>47^3>10^5$$

Comment: But what can be the possible number of digits when 30 digit number is cubed?

Comment: @NilabjaBhattacharya Note that $$47^{3} \times \left(10^{28}\right)^3$$has its number of digits restricted.